# Named query on abstract entity

Tags: entity, abstract, named

I have 3 entities in hierarchy:

**Request.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Request")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="REQUEST_TYPE", discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.INTEGER)
@NamedQuery(name="getRequestsById", query="select r from Request r where r.id=:id and r.status=100")
public abstract class Request implemenst Serializable {
...
}
```

**MedicineRequest.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="MED_REQUEST")
public abstract class MedicineRequest extends Request {
...
}
```

**ExtendedMedicineRequest.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="EXT_MED_REQUEST")
@DiscriminatorValue("1")
public class ExtendedMedicineRequest extends MedicineRequest {
...
}
```

Where I'm trying to run the above query, `getRequestsById`, I'm getting the following error message:

> Cannot instantiate abstract class of type "Request" with object id "Request-RequestPK@c49aa166"; this may indicate that the inheritance discriminator for the class is not configured correctly.

All the entities are defined properly in persistance.xml, name of the discriminator column is correct too. What can be the matter??

Answer (score 0):

No, it's ok to the entity to be abstract. 
But I found the reason. The query is generic, so it requests instantiation of sons of this entity. One of sons has relationship to other entity that uses enum from the utility jar. But...jpa project has this jar on the build path, wheh the EAR project doesn't include this jar in module list, so finally, the jar wasn't on the classpath in runtime. The error message was commonly irrelevant in this case.

Answer (score -1):

The reason is "Cannot instantiate abstract class of type", your Request class is abstract. Why? It's an entity then it SHOULDN'T be abstract.

Comment: No, it's ok to the entity to be abstract.